# Android Connect to ASP.net Without Deploy it to IIS

Tags: android, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Is there any way to connect Android project to my WEB API ASP.net without deploy that WEB API to IIS Server, because some  Dynamic AX service refference didn't work properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpListener and OWIN self-hosting to open a port from the process. This is how you start new web listener http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/07/09/getting-started-with-owin-katana-and-vs2013.aspx, and you can also check how to "Creating a Self-Hosted OWIN-Based Web Api" section here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/869223/ASP-NET-Web-Api-Create-a-Self-Hosted-OWIN-Based-We